# AppleScript – Pages export to PDF fails due to Sandbox permissions

Tags: applescript, automator, pdf, permission, pages

I'm trying to create an Automator workflow to export selected Pages documents to PDF. So far, everything goes well, except for the final export step.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with _document in input

        tell application "Finder"
            set _directory to get container of file _document

            set _documentName to name of _document
            if _documentName ends with ".pages" then ¬
                set _documentName to text 1 thru -7 of _documentName

            set _PDFName to _documentName & ".pdf"
            set _incrementIndex to 1
            repeat until not (exists file _PDFName of _directory)
                set _PDFName to ¬
                    _documentName & "-" & (_incrementIndex as string) & ".pdf"
                set _incrementIndex to _incrementIndex + 1
            end repeat

            set _location to (_directory as string) & _PDFName
        end tell

        --set _location to (POSIX file of _location)

        tell application "Pages"

            activate
            open _document

            with timeout of 1200 seconds
                export front document to file _location as PDF
            end timeout

            close front document

        end tell

    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

This gives me a Sandbox permissions error.

```
error   17:49:38.117966 +0100   sandboxd    SandboxViolation: Pages(3846) deny file-write-create /Users/brunoscheele/Desktop/Test.pdf
Violation:       deny file-write-create
```

After reading up on it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/180511/44633), it looked like I could fix this by changing `_location` to a `POSIX file`.

So I added;

```
--set _location to (POSIX file _location)
```

However, that then gives me the error:

*Pages got an error: "macOS:Users:brunoscheele:Desktop:Test.pdf" could not be interpreted as a file URL.*

Using `export front document to (POSIX file _location) as PDF` gives me the same error.

Does anyone know how to set the `_location` properly, so you don't run into permission issues?

Comment: Please include the macOS version in your question.

Comment: @ChrisPage The latest, always. But thanks for chiming in! And there was an answer in the meantime, check it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line before your exporting step:

```
open for access file _location
```

I'm guessing you're using macOS Sierra. This is a known issue. I could only make my code work by using the above step before my export started. Make sure you don't put that line inside a tell block.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. Edit your export line to look like this:

```
export front document to file _location as PDF
```

It's the word "file" that you were missing.

Note: I tried the script again and it did not work, even with the word "file" added. However, while experimenting I found that if I changed this line:

```
set _location to (_directory as string) & _PDFName
```

to

```
set _location to (_directory as string)
```

then the script would of course error. But then, if I undid the change, so the line again looked like this:

```
set _location to (_directory as string) & _PDFName
```

the script began to work! I am using Pages 6.0.5, macOS 10.12.2.

I can't say what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sadly, that was actually what gives the current permission errors. The script I originally pasted was after a couple of experiments, which is why I omitted it accidentily. See the updated original. Looks like it's a new error, considering this tweet; https://twitter.com/MACAUTOMATION/status/810997383672655872 . Any other insights?

Comment: I edited my answer to show how I made the script work. Maybe it will work for you the same way.

Comment: "could not be interpreted as a file url"  on both os x 10.2.2 and 10.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a script I was working on. It does indeed seem to be permissions related. The way I got round it was by creating the PDF inside the Pages file package. So, if your Pages file is at:

```
Macintosh HD:Users:Admin:Desktop:myfile.pages
```

...then create your PDF at:

```
Macintosh HD:Users:Admin:Desktop:myfile.pages:myfile.pdf
```

There's a code sample of the code where I ran into this problem, and a sample of how I solved it here:

https://www.ghostotter.com/using-automator-convert-pages-pdf/

Hope that helps!